# How to selected multiple select with explode

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

So, I have `$dp->isi = "1,2,3,4"`

```
<select name="isi[]" class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Choose"
                    style="width: 100%;">
                <?php foreach ($data->result() as $db) : ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $db->id;?>"
                <?php if ($db->id == explode(',',$dp->isi)) { ?>
                selected="selected"<?php } ?>>
                <?php echo $db->name; ?>
                </option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
```

Using codeIgniter, I want `$dp->isi` value to be selected on multipleselect.

Comment: please provide full example with contents of the database and variables

Comment: `explode` returns __array__, `$db->id` is not array. So they will never be equal.

Comment: instead of `if ($db->id == explode(',',$dp->isi))` use `if (in_array($db->id, explode(',',$dp->isi)))`

Comment: Okay, fixed by @sintakonte Thank you!